# Multisite (with nested paths) wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: multisite, redirect

Hi I have hacked Wordpress to allow nested paths in multisites, these blogs start with a `/s/`.  Eg `blogdomain.com/s/blog-name` .  Though the main blog still sits on `blogdomain.com`.

This works fine to display the sites, but the wp-admin goes into a redirect loop.  I presume this is something I need add to the ht access to redirect pages to the correct location.

What is the correct rule to do this, I have tried :
`RewriteRule ^/s/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /s/$2/wp-admin/index.php`

Though this does not work.
`

Comment: Does you run into redirect look while accessing to `network`? or just admin/content/includes?

Comment: Hi Butuzov, the loop only occurs when trying to access wp-admin/content/includes on the sites which use the nested paths.  Network admin works fine, as do sites without the nested paths.